# Jaspersoft iReport Designer Stretch With Overflow not working if field is a group

Tags: overflow, ireport, stretch

Using 4.5.0 for numerous reports, each using the same datafield SVC_METH_NM. Have no problem word wrapping (using Stretch With Overflow) the datafield SVC_METH_NM unless the field is a group. When the field is a Group, the data is truncated instead of wrapped. If I set the Evaluation Time to Now, which blanks out the Evaluation group, it wraps correctly (but the report doesn't display properly). I tried removing the fields in the line immediately below, and have tried playing with the Position Type and Stretch Type options, to no avail.

```
<group name="ServiceMethodName">
<groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{SVC_METH_NM}]]></groupExpression>
<groupHeader>
<band height="20">
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="ServiceMethodName">
<reportElement x="23" y="0" width="180" height="20" printWhenGroupChanges="ServiceMethodName"/>
<textElement>
<font isBold="true" isItalic="false"/></textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SVC_METH_NM}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 3):

I am dealing with this issue right now. Did you find a solution? I was hoping to avoid it, but think I'll have to try and solve the problem using subreport(s). Fairly certain I can display the text appropriately that way, but feel like I shouldn't have to overcomplicate things with subreports.

Edit: TESTED SOLUTION - Put a subreport in your group header. Query for the subreport should be "select * from dual" since you will actually be passing all data in from the master report. Pass the field(s) to the subreport as parameters, and display them exactly as you would in the group header, but do it in the detail band.  iReport will handle the wrapping of the text since it's in the detail band.  Make sure Print When Detail Overflows is set on the subreport, and Stretch With Overflow is set on your subreport field.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am aware this doesn't directly answer the question.  I was hoping the original poster had resolved their issue and could share the solution.  I was also sharing what I believe would be a solution, but had not done a POC yet.  I obviously have no reputation, and likely won't gain any without posting something that can in fact help others with this problem.  Instead of stating the obvious that it doesn't directly answer the question and downvoting, maybe you should ask if my proposed solution ended up working for me.  I will post the results of my proposed solution.

Comment: (I did not down vote, but ..) Yep, understood. Normally I would have suggested leaving a comment, but that requires a [50+ reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Just keep in mind Stack Overflow [works differently than a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Its Q&A format is deliberately spartan. Responses that are perceived as questions or non-answers are typically deleted, so others do not have to sift through tons of information to find answers. But you can always [expand your response](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20061065/edit) into a full fledged answer.

Comment: BTW, ignore the multiple "this is not an answer ..." comments. That text is generated by the system automatically.

Comment: Leigh, understood but I felt what I had at the time could prove helpful to someone until I had time for testing a full answer.  I've edited the answer after testing it, so can you upvote and/or mark as correct?  Or can only the person who asked the question do that?

Comment: Thanks for expanding it into an answer that will help the next guy. Yes, only the OP can mark it as correct.